# SharedAxisTransition for Flutter is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement [Shared Axis Transition](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/SharedAxisTransition-class.html) between two tabs.

When the `bottomNavigationBar` is tapped, the `selectedIndex` goes from 0 to 1, and vice versa. During that change, the transition should animate. My code does not have any errors but no animations occurs.

Appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

```
body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> primaryAnimation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return SharedAxisTransition(
              animation: primaryAnimation,
              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
              child: child);
        },
        child: selectedIndex == 0
            ? AnimationLimiter(
                child: AnimatedList(
                  key: _key,
                  initialItemCount: db.dailyList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                    return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                      position: index,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                      child: SlideAnimation(
                        verticalOffset: 50.0,
                        child: FadeInAnimation(
                          child: SizeTransition(
                            sizeFactor: animation,
                            child: Tile(
                              title: db.dailyList[index][0],
                              goalAchieved: db.dailyList[index][1],
                              onChanged: (value) =>
                                  {checkBoxChanged(value, index)},
                              deleteFunction: (context) => deleteGoal(index),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : AnimationLimiter(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dbAchieved.dailyAchievedList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return AchievedTile(
                      title: dbAchieved.dailyAchievedList[index][0],
                      deleteFunction: (context) => deleteAchievedGoal(index),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.fact_check_outlined), label: 'Carpe Diem'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.done), label: 'Achieved')
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out, i just need to declare a key for each of the AnimationLimiter for it to work. I just added the following:

`static const dailyKey = Key('dailyKey');`
`static const dailyAcheivedKey = Key('dailyAchievedKey');`

and then adding it in the AnimationLimiter

`key: dailyKey`
`key: dailyAchievedKey`